# Ошибка Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я новичок в React, поэтому не бейте. У меня есть метод в классе:

```
    showProductLists() {
        Object.keys(responseAPI).forEach(function(item, index, responseAPI) {
            arr.push(
                <SimpleCell
                    description='Нажми, чтобы отредактировать список'
                    onClick={() => this.test}
                >
                    {item}
                </SimpleCell>
         this.setState({ productLists: arr }) 
}
```

Данный метод прогоняет объект `responseAPI`, push в массив и `setState`.
В `render()` отображаю с помощью `{this.state.productLists}`. При нажатии `onClick={() => this.test}` хочу вызвать метод `test`:

```
test() {
    console.log('тест') //к примеру
}
```

Но при нажатии, возникает ошибка: `Cannot read property of 'test' undefined`. Я пробовал `this.test = this.test.bind(this);`, но та же ошибка. Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена! В **function** нельзя обращаться к `this.*`.

Поэтому, строчку `forEach(function(item, index, responseAPI) {` меняем на: `forEach((item, index, responseAPI) => {`.